# C++ Recognize UTF-8 or Hebrew languague

Tags: c++, string, encoding, hebrew, wstring

I'm working on some code that his target it recognize if the strings equal
Have two type of string - string 1 came from text file , string 2 came from server side from chat packet
i try very different options , this my last trying but nothing success the sentence not recognize has equal at all for example this string on text file "בדיקה" and the string that came from packet side is "בדיקה" too and still nothing equal
`

```
    if(gSentenceEvent.IsRunning())
    {
         std::string s = lpMsg->message;
    int Len = strlen(gSentenceEvent.RandomSentence);
    
          std::string str;
            str.assign(gSentenceEvent.RandomSentence, gSentenceEvent.RandomSentence + Len);
        if (str.compare(s) == 0)
        {
            gSentenceEvent.SetRunning(false);
            gNotice.GCNoticeSendToAll(0,0,0,0,0,0,gMessage.GetMessage(1130));
            gNotice.GCNoticeSendToAll(0,0,0,0,0,0,gMessage.GetMessage(1127),lpObj->Name);
        }
        else
        {
            gNotice.GCNoticeSendToAll(0,0,0,0,0,0,"%s Try %s\n",lpObj->Name,s);
            gNotice.GCNoticeSendToAll(0,0,0,0,0,0,"Answer Is %s\n",str);
        }
        
    }
```

`
if someone have any idea for solving the issue i will be happy to hear some ways that recognize it well
Thanks in advance !

trying convert the text for wstring as well but still nothing

Comment: Printout / display the hex value of each character of the 2 strings.

Comment: For UTF-8 Hebrew characters are unique codes. Do you mean that the Hebrew may come in a different encoding, and that you are trying to identify it as Hebrew?

Comment: `compare` returns zero if two strings are equal, but it knows nothing about Hebrew or UTF-8. Therefore you need to print out each **byte** of the two strings to understand exactly where and why they are not comparing equal. Do that and report back here with the results.

Comment: As @Dúthomhas says this almost certainly an encoding issue. Do you think both strings are UTF-8 or are you not sure? Again printing out the byte values will show what encoding is being used.

Answer (score 0):

when i check the hex value of both sentence even they equal

```
gNotice.GCNoticeSendToAll(0,0,0,0,0,0,"%.2X",lpMsg->message);
    gNotice.GCNoticeSendToAll(0,0,0,0,0,0,"%.2X",gSentenceEvent.RandomSentence);
```

that really came different from example "בדיקהה 3" On both sides
ServerSide = 22B6970
TextFile = D9C0B0

Comment: Using [unicode to hex converter](https://onlineunicodetools.com/convert-unicode-to-hex?input=%D7%91%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%94%D7%94%203&prefix=true&padding=true&spacing=true&output-encoding=utf8&bom=false) I get the following hex data `0xd7 0x91 0xd7 0x93 0xd7 0x99 0xd7 0xa7 0xd7 0x94 0xd7 0x94 0x20 0x33` or `d7 91 d7 93 d7 99 d7 a7 d7 94 d7 94 20 33`.  You don't seem to have output enough hex characters for the length of the test data.